# Get count from Resource Model Collection

Tags: magento2.2, resource-model

I want to get the collection's count by using this method :

```
public function getCount()
    {
        $connection = $this->getConnection();
        $select = $connection->select();
        $select->from($this->getEntityTable(), 'COUNT(*)');
        $result = (int)$connection->fetchOne($select);
        return $result;
    }
```

in the file `Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Item\Collection.php`

I have the following error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Item\Collection::getEntityTable() in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\app\code\Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Item\Collection.php:31 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\app\code\Vendor\Module\Block\Crud.php(43)
```

Am I missing something in the constructor ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, I should call `getMainTable()` and not `getEntityTable()`.